# data and structure cleansing of excel sheets

Tags: excel, database

I have over 6,000 excel sheets.  While all the sheets describe the same thing, they are independently formatted.  They all have between 9 and 13 columns, but they are out of order, the column names are independently misspelled, and they may or may not have a second, or third, column header.

I am currently trying in python to read cells in a left-down-right-up motion to attempt to locate the same data, but there is physically too many differences in structure names, column ordering, and data definitions to lock them in one a time.  Is there a tool that I can use to read these documents and conform them to a single format, via a rapid mapping function?

Thanks much.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to data quality services in SQL Server?  There is also an associated (and dependent) Excel-Add in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/master-data-services/install-windows/enable-data-quality-services-integration-with-master-data-services  Painful to set up but easy to maintain.

Comment: Do you have more information on the topic?  How would I map 6000 documents to SQL Server using MDS?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, it's the ***Ultimate Data Horror Story***.

I want to ask how you ever let it get this way... but I actually don't want to know; I'm already going to have nightmares about this.

It's like that Hoarding show on TV, but with data.

[image: data hoarding]

No, I'm afraid that if you can't even identify a pattern then there's no magic function that will be able to either.

But that doesn't mean it's a lost cause.  It's just going to need some human interaction, and there are ways to minimize the pain.

What you need is a custom interface that will load the documents one by one, and will walk a human through clicking each relevant column or area, and then automatically load the next document.

There would also need to be buttons for sorting things like obvious garbage sheets (blanks?), "unknowns" (that get put in a folder for advanced research later), and other "unpredictables" may come up during the process.

Also, perhaps once you get into it, you'll notice a pattern you're not thinking of, like maybe *"the person who handled the files from 2002 to 2004 set them up *this* way"*, or, *"when Budget is misspelled, it's always either Bugdet or Budteg".*

In this scope, little patterns like that can make a big difference.

Depending on your coding skills, you may or may not need outside assistance with this.  I assume this is not data that can just get thrown out, or you wouldn't be asking...

If each document took an average of 20 seconds to process, that would be about **33 hours** in total.  An hour a day an it's done in a **month**.  Or someone full-time, and it's done in a **week**.

Do you have a budget you can throw at this?  [Data archaeology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_archaeology) is an actual thing!  Hell, I'll do it for you for the right price...  (wouldn't break the bank, depending on how urgent it is, of course!)

Either way, this ain't going to be fun for "someone"...

[image: scary data]